# GPG error: https://download.01.org trusty InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available

Tags: linux, ubuntu, updates, apt-get, packages

Running `apt-get update` shows the following error:

> W: GPG error: https://download.01.org trusty InRelease: The following
>   signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not
>   available: NO_PUBKEY

Answer (score 5):

Does your error message spit out some hex hash?  Because this is easily solvable by running this command:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys [YOUR HASH HERE]
```

Then running `apt-get update` again:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

And you should be good to go.

Answer (score 2):

It would be worth adding that these specific apt repositories are *intel* repositories for their own drivers, and you wouldn't generally have the keys for them preinstalled in a standard ubuntu install. As such, as per [the instructions on intel's driver page](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/2014/intelr-graphics-installer-1.0.6-linux) - these are for 1.06, so you may want to check [the latest](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/blogs) update , you need to add the gpg keys for the 01.org repositories

```
wget --no-check-certificate https://download.01.org/gfx/RPM-GPG-KEY-ilg -O - | \
sudo apt-key add -

wget --no-check-certificate https://download.01.org/gfx/RPM-GPG-KEY-ilg-2 -O - | \
sudo apt-key add
```

Copy and paste these two lines in order to add the keys, update, and try again.

Comment: https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/2014/intelr-graphics-installer-linux-1.0.7

Answer (score 0):

Update for everyone with problems: It seems the key expired on December 25th, sent Intel an email.

You can verify this with

```
apt-key list | grep expired -C3
```