# What is this error when trying to update Ubuntu?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu

I am need of updating my Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS machine so I can update NodeJS to the latest version.

Whenever I run `sudo apt update` I get this error:

```shell
The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY {KEY}
```

I get it for two keys:

```
DEEBD57F917C83E3
23F3D4EA75716059
```

When I use the command below it works for one key but I still get the same errors when running the update command again.

```shell
apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys {KEY}
```

Comment: See https://chrisjean.com/fix-apt-get-update-the-following-signatures-couldnt-be-verified-because-the-public-key-is-not-available/ and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70789307/how-to-fix-the-following-signatures-couldnt-be-verified-because-the-public-key

Comment: Provide the key signature so we can help you otherwise this question is impossible to answer

Comment: @Ramhound Just added

Comment: Can you run `apt-key list | grep expired -C3` (suggested by https://superuser.com/questions/820833) which also lists another method to potentially fix.

Comment: @Mokubai All I get is `Warning: apt-key output should not be parsed (stdout is not a terminal)`

Comment: You can extrapolate the solution for the other key [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13065/how-do-i-fix-the-gpg-error-no-pubkey#:~:text=To%20solve%20this%20problem%20use%20this%20command%3A%20gpg,which%20adds%20the%20key%20to%20apt%20trusted%20keys.)